# Convergence of the sequence $\sum \frac{n+5}{\sqrt{n^5 - 10n+10}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck on a question and would really appreciate if anyone can give some help.

> Determine whether the series:
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+5}{\sqrt{n^5 - 10n+10}}$$
> converges or not.

I am trying to use comparison test and chop down a fair amount of the expression. Here is what I attempted:

$$x_n < \frac{n+5}{\sqrt{n^5-10n}} = \frac{n+5}{n^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{n^4-10}}$$

Take n > 5, that gives
$$x_n < \frac{2n}{n^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{n^4 - n^3}} = \frac{2}{n\sqrt{n-1}}.$$

I cannot get the last $\sqrt{n-1}$ out of the way...other than maybe argue because I am taking $n$ to infinity it doesn't matter if it has a $n-1$ or $n$ ...while that does feels a bit sketchy...

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{20n}{n^3+10}$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{12n^2}{n^3+10}$ diverges

Comment: ahhhh very sorry i just realized i totally typed a wrong question...

Comment: $n-1 \geq \frac n 2$ for $n>1$

Comment: oooh that's also a nice way of solving it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac2{n\sqrt{n-1}}}{\frac1{n^{3/2}}}=2.$$So, since the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}$ converges, so does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac2{n\sqrt{n-1}}$.

Comment: ok hmm now I do remember my TA mentioned something similar in recitation...ik it's probably really obvious but is there a reason the larger limit above (lim \frac{2}{n \sqrt{n-1} ....) equals to 2? I was trying to simplify it myself and can only get it done to \frac{2 \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-1}} ....

Comment: also an additional question if it's ok: I have not encounter this particular logic before (we just started sequence in my class). would this logic work because if a sequence \sum xn is convergent, then {xn} would have to be convergent --> meaning if xn = an/bn, and an or bn is not convergent (i.e. xn not convergent), then \sum xn could not be convergent?

Comment: It's because$$\frac{\frac2{n\sqrt{n-1}}}{\frac1{n^{3/2}}}=\frac{2n\sqrt n}{n\sqrt{n-1}}.$$

Comment: The argument that I have used was based upon the fact that, given two series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ of real numbers greater than $0$, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}\in(0,\infty)$, then either both series converge or both of them diverge.

Comment: I actually have not encounter the argument before...I will definitely look into it! Thanks a lot for the clarification & answering additional question!